# syntax highlighting for indentation sensitive multiline comment

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I want to create syntax highlighting for indentation sensitive language that I'm designing, my question is how to highlight multiline comment that begins with #!
something like this

```
#! xxxxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
```

or

```
func arg1 arg2 #! xxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxx
                xxxxxxxxx
                xxxxxx
                  xxxxxx
  arg3
  arg4
```

**Edit**
I found a solution for the first example

```
syn match CommentBlock /\( *\)#!.*\n\(\1 .*\n\)*/
```

Comment: What identifies the end of the comment?

Comment: if the next line after #! have a shorter indentation from where #! is located it then identified as the end of the comment

Comment: Your example would then make identifying the comment difficult as #! has no indentation. Does the comment end at arg3 or the second lot of xxxxxx?\

Comment: it ends at arg3, matching the first example ( with indentation for #! ) would be fine

Comment: See `:h syn-region`

Comment: thanks but a region need an end pattern and don't recognize indentation

Comment: You can make patterns match indentation.

Comment: I tried this `syn match dreamComment /\( *\)#!.*\n\(\1 .+\n\)*/ contains=@Spell,dreamTodo` for the first example but it only match the first line, if you could help me out to make it work for multiline that would be great

Comment: I've got something that kind of works. It has some weird behavior, but maybe you can mess around with it a bit. I used `\_.` to match everything including newlines, and I used a negative lookahead `\(\)\@!`. Here it is: `syn match dreamComment /\( *\) #!\_.*\n\ze\1\(\S\)\@!/`

Comment: strangely enough, it's seems my own match start working maybe I didn't rerun vim, but still don't know what to do about the second example

Comment: If people using your langage have lines that are bigger than their screen sizes, how can they differentiate the end of comments from something that looks "less indented" but is in fact the end of the previous lines that just wraps around spaces?  ie : are you sure you do NOT want something to end multi lines comments? seems very confusing and error prone, to me... (may make the code appear to do "this" when it fact it does "that")

Comment: I don't think it's a big problem, we could turn off line-wrapping in the editor plugin